# Identify a pullback line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, pullback, line-bundles

Consider a degree $d$ map $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^m$ for $d \geq 1$ and $m \geq 2$, together with a line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(l)$ over $\mathbb{P}^m$ for $l \geq 1$. Then we have a pullback line bundle $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(l)$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$.

**Is $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(l) \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(dl)$ always true?**

Let $[x_0,x_1]$ and $[y_0, \dots, y_m]$ be the homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^m$, respectively. Then one can argue that a degree $l$ homogeneous polynomial in $y_0, \dots, y_m$ pullbacks to a degree $dl$ homogeneous polynomial in $x_0$ and $x_1$. But these may not span the global sections $H^0 (\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(dl))$. For example, consider $m = 2$ and $l=3$, and a degree $2$ map $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ defined by
$$[x_0,x_1] \mapsto [x_0^2,x_1^2,0].$$
Then the global section $x_0^5x_1$ in $H^0 (\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(6))$ is missing from the pullbacks of degree $3$ polynomials in $y_0,y_1,y_2$.

What's wrong with the above argument?

Comment: You are confusing a sheaf and its space of global sections. It is true that $f^*\mathcal{O}(l) \cong \mathcal{O}(dl)$, but the map $f^* : H^0(\mathbb{P}^m, \mathcal{O}(l)) \to H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(dl))$ need not be an isomorphism.

Comment: There's no reason for the map on the global sections to be an isomorphism, if $E$ is a vector bundle then $f^{\star}: H^0(X, E)\to H^0(Y, f^{\star}E)$ needs not be an isomorphism. Think of the case where $Y$ is a point and $f$ the closed immersion for instance.

Comment: Well that's pretty much what Sasha already said, I'll leave my comment for the example with the inclusion of a point, which might (?) be enlightenning.

Comment: Also, to answer your first question, notice that unsing the compatibility of the pull back with the tensor product, you just have to prove the result for $\ell=1$, but then it's more or less obvious.

Comment: @Sasha So a stronger statement is the map $f^*: H^0(\mathbb{P}^m, \mathcal{O}(l)) \to H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(dl))$ may be neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: @YuhangChen: Definitely it can.

Comment: @Ahr I also thought about reducing to prove $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(1) \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d)$. I agree it's kinda obvious since a generic rational curve of degree $d$ intersects a generic hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^m$ at $d$ points. But how to prove it rigorously? Alternatively, one can directly argue that the local sections of $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(1)$ generate all forms $g(x_0,x_1)/h(x_0,x_1)$ where $\text{deg}\ g - \text{deg}\ h = d$.

Comment: This comes for the usual proposition that giving a morphism in $P^n$ is the same as giving a line bundle $L$ and $n+1$ sections that generates the fiber at every point, moreover this implies that $L=f^*O(1)$ by the morphism you constructed. The proof is indeed to do a local calculation and mapping $x$ to $[s_0(x)/s_j(x):...:s_{n+1}(x)/s_j(x)]$ over $s_j(x)\neq 0$ which is tantamount to saying that the cocycles of $L$ are the same as the ones of $f^*O(1)$ and thus the bundles are isomorphic.

Comment: Here saying that you have a map $P^1\to P^m$ given by $m+1$ homogenous polynomial of degree $d$ si saying that you take $(1+m)$ sections of $O(d)$ over $P^1$ and apply the proposition I mentionned.

Comment: If you prefer you have locals maps $L(U_i)\to f^*O(1)(U_i)$ where $U_i=\{x\in X, s_{i,x}\notin \mathfrak{m}_xL_x\}$ given by $s_i\mapsto x_i$. These maps glue together.

Comment: There's a lot of good discussion in the comments which I think when put together would constitute an answer I'd be interested in upvoting. Would you care to compile this in to an answer, @Ahr?

Comment: Sure I'll put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by Sasha, the pull back map need not be an isomorphism on global sections.
If you take $E$ a vector bundle on a scheme $X$ and a map $f: Y\to X$ you get a map $f^*: H^0(X, E)\to H^0(Y, f^*E)$ which is not an isomorphism in general (for instance take $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y=\mathbb{A}^n$ an affine subspace, or $Y=x$ a point).

To prove the mentionned claim:

$$f^*\mathcal O(\ell)\simeq \mathcal{O}(d\ell)$$
you may notice that it suffices to prove it for $\ell=1$ as $f^*(E\otimes F)\simeq f^*E\otimes f^*F$.

Then you have the following proposition (which is in Hartshorne for instance):

Assume that $X$ is an $R$-scheme, giving a morphism $f: X\to \mathbb{P}_R^n$ is the same as giving a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ over $X$ and $(n+1)$ sections $s_0,...,s_n$ of $\mathcal{L}$ generating the fiber at each point via the correspondance $\mathcal{L} \leftrightarrow f^*\mathcal{O}(1)$.

The proof is simply to notice that $X$ is covered by open subsets $U_i=\{x\in X|s_i(x)\neq 0\}$, which may not be affine, but for any affine $V$ in $U_i$ you get a morphism $V\to V_i\simeq \mathbb{A}^n$ (viewed as the complement of the hyperplane $x_i=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^n)$ given by $(s_0/s_i,...,s_n/s_i)$, these morphisms all agree and thus you get a well defined morphism $U_i\to V_i$, which again agree on overlaps and you get a well defined morphism $X\to \mathbb{P}^n$.

You also get a morphism $\mathcal{L}\to f^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$ sending, over $U_i$ the section $s_i$ to $x_i$, these maps by definition glue together to give you an isomorphism of line bundles.

For more details you can look up in Hartshorne.

Now if you take a morphism $f: \mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^m$ given by $(m+1)$ homogenous polynomial of degree $d$ thus by $m+1$ sections of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ you get by the mentionned claim applying the proposition.

A small note: here I assumed that you took $f$ directly given by homogenous polynomials of degree $d$, depending on your definition of degree you may use a slightly different approach (like the projection formula if your definition comes from intersection theory).
In any case in view of the aforementionned proposition and the fact a line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$ if always of the form $\mathcal{O}(d)$ for some $d$, a morphism of degree $d$ from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{P}^m$ will always be given by sections of $\mathcal{O}(d)$ i.e by $m+1$ homogenous polynomials of degree $d$.

Comment: Thanks for writing out a detailed answer. To prove the isomorphism $\mathcal{L} \cong f^*\mathcal{O}(1)$, one can use that pullback preserves transition functions. The transition function of $f^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ from $f^{-1}(U_i)$ to $f^{-1}(U_j)$ is $g_{ji} = f^*(x_i/x_j) = s_i/s_j$, which is precisely the corresponding transition function of $\mathcal{L}$.